# Proving that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)$ is smaller or equal to $\operatorname{rank}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I am struggling with proving the theorem that if $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices, then:

> $$\operatorname{rank}(AB)\leq \operatorname{rank}(B)$$

Could anyone suggest me a hint?
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: You're asking quite a few "no effort" questions Marco, tread softly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every row of $AB$ is a linear combination of the rows of $B$. Therefore, the dimension of the row space of $AB$ cannot be bigger than the dimension of the row space of $B$.

To see that every row of $AB$ is a linear combination of the rows of $B$, just look at how matrix multiplication is done: the $k$th row of $AB$ is $A_k B$ where $A_k$ is the $k$th row of $A$.  There are as many scalars in that row as there are rows of $B$.  The $\ell$th entry in the row $A_k$ gets multiplied by the $\ell$ row of $B$, and then those get added up from $\ell=1$ to $\ell=$ the number of rows of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Look at those matrices as linear transformations and use [Rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: Can I write the following? Matrix $A$ and $B$ corresponds to linear transformations $T$ and $S$ respectively, such that $T,S: V \rightarrow V$. Then $Im(TS(U))=Im(T(S(U)))  \subseteq Im(S(U))$, so that $rank(TS) \leq rank(S)$ and so $rank(AB) \leq rank(B)$. Am I right?

Comment: Ah, as $Im(S) \subseteq V$, then $Im(T(S)) \subseteq Im(T)$. But well, this proves that $rank(AB) \leq rank(A)$, right?

Comment: @marco11 Please, be careful with the notation: who is $U$? also, the $Im$ "operator" is only applied to linear transformation, not sets. The argument would be "since $S(V)\subseteq V$, $TS(V)\subseteq T(V)$ and therefore $\operatorname{rank}(TS)\leq \operatorname{rank}(T)$", however, you're trying to prove $\operatorname{rank}(TS)\leq \operatorname{rank}(S)$. Argue with the fact that the rank of a matrix and its transpose are equal.

Comment: @Daniel I guess there is a typo in your comment above. Should not it be $$rank(TS)\leq rank(T)$$

Answer (score 1):

here is another way too look at it. every row $i$ of $AB$ is a linear combination of the rows of $B$ weighted by the row $i$ of $A.$ therefore the row space of $AB$ is contained in the row space of $B.$ now use the fact that rank of matrix is the dimension of its row space.

Answer (score 0):

let the vecotor x ϵ c(AB). c(AB) denotes the column space of AB. then

x=ABy for some vector y

x=Az ϵ c(AB) ,where z=by
hence c(AB) is a subspace C(A)
=>dim[c(AB)] ≤dim c(A)
rank(AB)≤rank(A)